# NSString function

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nslog

I get a null return when i try out my NSString function.

```
//Track.m

static NSString* trackUrl;
//static NSString* getTrackNumberUrl;

@implementation Track

- (NSString*)trackUrl {
    return @"http://site.com/?a=";
}

- (NSString*)setTrackNumberUrl:(NSString*)trackNumberUrl {
    if (trackUrl != trackNumberUrl) {
        return [trackUrl stringByAppendingFormat:trackNumberUrl];
    }

 return @"Error no trackNumber";
}

- (NSString*)getTrackNumberUrl:(NSString*)trackNumber {
 return [[[self alloc] setTrackNumberUrl:trackNumber] autorelease];
}

@end
```

MainView.m, just to show the return answer in NSlog

```
- (NSString *) trackNumber{
 return [track getTrackNumberUrl:@"86147224549XX"];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 NSLog(trackNumber);
}
```

I get a null return answer? Have i miss something? Thanks.

Edit some in Track.m

```
- (NSString*)setTrackNumberUrl:(NSString*)trackNumberUrl {
    if (trackUrl != trackNumberUrl) {
        return [trackUrl stringByAppendingString:trackNumberUrl];
    }

    return @"Error no trackNumber";
}

- (NSString*)getTrackNumberUrl:(NSString*)trackNumber {
    return [[[Track alloc] setTrackNumberUrl:trackNumber] init];
}
```

This is how it should work.

getTrackNumberUrl --> setTrackNumberUrl --> trackUrl (return) --> setTrackNumberUrl + trackNumber --> getTrackNumberUrl (trackNumberUrl = trackUrl + trackNumber)

---

I have this code to set reference to Track

```
@class Track;

@interface MainView : UIView {


    Track *track;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Track *track;
```

Well if don't should use self alloc, what should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of problems with your code.

```
return [trackUrl stringByAppendingFormat:trackNumberUrl];
```

You should not use an arbitrary string as a format, because if it contains a format specifier like "%d" then the method will go looking for a variable that isn't there, and will likely crash. You should use `stringByAppendingString:` instead. However, that doesn't seem to be what you want here, since the method name is `setTrackNumberUrl:`. If you want to change the value of the `trackUrl` variable, you can't call `stringByAppendingFormat:`; all that does is return a new string and leave the original alone. I think you simply want something like

```
[trackUrl release];
trackUrl = [trackNumberUrl retain];
```

Another problem:

```
return [[[self alloc] setTrackNumberUrl:trackNumber] autorelease];
```

In this context, `self` is an *instance* of Track. An instance won't understand the `alloc` message, that must be sent to a class. It will return a new instance, to which you should send an `init` message. So you would do something like `[[Track alloc] init]`.

```
NSLog(trackNumber);
```

The first parameter to NSLog is a format string, so for the same reasons as above you shouldn't use a variable, you should do something like this: `NSLog(@"%@", trackNumber);` That line of code prints the value of the variable, trackNumber. Considering that you have a method named `trackNumber` just above it, I wonder if what you really want to do is call the method and get the result. In that case, you need to write it as `[self trackNumber]` which will call the method and return an NSString.

Comment: "You should initialize trackUrl to nil." 
Static variables are automatically initialized to zero.

Comment: I want to call the getTrackNumberUrl function in Track. The getTrackNumberUrl collect information from setTrackNumberUrl how are getting the base url from trackUrl.

Comment: I have fix that you write, but it still return null

Comment: Great explanation. I think this code is a little hopeless... BUt please remove the comment about initialization of static variable - it's incorrect, as KennyTM pointed out.

Comment: @KennyTM: Thanks, I didn't know where I learned to be so defensive.

Comment: Yes it was greate explanation. But it still return null value.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `track` is `nil` in the `trackNumber` - have you set it to a correct reference to a `Track` object?

Also, this code

```
- (NSString*)getTrackNumberUrl:(NSString*)trackNumber {
    return [[[self alloc] setTrackNumberUrl:trackNumber] autorelease];
}
```

is incorrect. Why are you using `[self alloc]`? You're allocating a new `Track` object (using a static method on an object reference, not on a class name, which is an error), setting it's track number URL, and returning an autoreleased `NSString`, but you're leaking the `Track` object you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

```
return [trackUrl stringByAppendingFormat:trackNumberUrl];
```

I'm not sure bout this one,
try using it as a format for string.

```
 return [trackUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",trackNumberUrl];
```